# Reading raw http request by name value

Tags: python, httprequest

Given the data below, I am trying the get the value of each of the content-disposition by name. For example get the subject, or to values. For example, I would like to be able to look for "html" and it will give me:

> `<html><body><strong>Hello SendGrid!</body></html>`

Im not sure how I should do this? Had something like this in mind:

> subject = full_msg[full_msg.find('Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name="subject"')+len('Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name="subject"'):full_msg.rfind('--xYzZY')].strip()

```
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="headers"

MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 0.0.0.0 with HTTP; Wed, 10 Aug 2016 18:10:13 -0700 (PDT)
From: Example User <test@example.com>
Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2016 18:10:13 -0700
Subject: Inbound Parse Test Data
To: inbound@inbound.example.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a113df448cad2d00539c16e89

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dkim"

{@sendgrid.com : pass}
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to"

inbound@inbound.example.com
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="html"

<html><body><strong>Hello SendGrid!</body></html>

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="from"

Example User <test@example.com>
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

Hello SendGrid!

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sender_ip"

0.0.0.0
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="envelope"

{"to":["inbound@inbound.example.com"],"from":"test@example.com"}
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachments"

0
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

Testing non-raw
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="charsets"

{"to":"UTF-8","html":"UTF-8","subject":"UTF-8","from":"UTF-8","text":"UTF-8"}
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SPF"

pass
--xYzZY--
```

Comment: As your text seem to be RFC822 serialized data, you could transform this text into Python objects tree using the email.parser module from the stdlib : https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#module-email.parser

Comment: Oops, I commented above before you removed the mail headers from the sample. So forget previous comment.

Comment: yea, that didnt work :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import email

full_msg = request.POST['email']
msg = email.message_from_string(full_msg)
from_address = msg["from"]
```